# Load latest version of a Google API?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-api, google-api-js-client

I'm not sure how to preface this. I'm working on an angular wrapper for the Google Client API (note: I'm doing this simply because I haven't found anything that works for me, so if you know of a Google API / Angular, let me know)

I'm trying to make this as generic as possible, so what I would like is something like a function that goes

```
function makeApiCall (library, collection, method, cb){

  gapi.client[library][collection][method](

}
```

Now if we notice, I'm not checking that the library has been loaded, and I'd like to load the library if it hasn't been already. Problem is that not all libraries from Google have the same version, and as of right now I do not know of a way to check the latest version.

I've tried somethings like the following

```
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'latest', cb);
gapi.client.load('calendar', 'release', cb);
```

I remember *a long* time ago you could use ... well one of those (can't remember which). Is there some way to do this now? Otherwise I'll have to figure something else out.

Comment: In [Google Loader](https://developers.google.com/loader/#versioning), they say `To always load the latest stable version of the API, request the version number without specifying a revision. So, using the above example, requesting version 2 loads the latest stable revision of the API, e.g., 2.2.3.` . Hope this helps

Comment: My problem is that I will not always be the one writing the ending code. I'm working on a very generic wrapper for the JS Gapi, some of those client libraries have version 1, some (like google calendar) have version 3 and as of right now I have no way to know what the latest version is.